# Update variable in React in class not extending component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to wrap my head around ReactJS and I am stumped with an issue where I want to be able to update the value of a local variable and return the updated value.

I've read about state and I've used that when working with React Components, however, this class is just defined as const and it doesn't extend React.Component.

Is there a different way I should be defining setting the variable?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```html
import React from 'react';

const WelcomeForm = ({welcome}) => {

    var welcomeMsg = 'Test';

    DynamicContentApi.loadDynamicContent('welcome_test').then((response) => {
       // response.text has content
       welcomeMsg = response.text;
    }).catch(() => {
        welcomeMsg = '';
    });

    return (
                <p>{welcomeMsg}</p> // Returns 'Test'
    );
};

export default WelcomeForm;
```

Comment: DynamicContentApi.loadDynamicContent( ) - what is that?

Comment: This is not a simplified version of the class. You are trying to use a stateless component as a stateful component. you can update as many variables as you want, but React won't re-render in a stateless component :)

Comment: Ordinary variable does not rerender the component when updated. If you want to write this logic here then i would recomment you to use `state` by extending `React.component`.

Comment: Other way would be to move `DynamicContentApi` logic above in the hierarchy and pass the result as a prop to this component.

Comment: [Tiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835111/2479481) is the correct approach to fix your problem. The reason your code doesn't work is because `loadDynamicContent` executes asynchronously, so by the time it completes, your component has already rendered with `'Test'`. And since `welcomeMsg` is just a local variable, it won't trigger a re-render when it changes (as it would if it were a prop or kept in state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option here is to change your **stateless component** to a **stateful component**.

> **Stateless components** are just JavaScript functions. They take in an
>   optional input, called prop.
>
> **Stateful components** offer more features, and with more features comes more baggage. The primary reason to choose class components (stateful) over functional components (stateless) is that they can have **state**, that is what you want to update to re-render.

Here is what you can do:

```
class WelcomeForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    welcomeMsg: ''
  }
  fetchFromApi() {
    DynamicContentApi.loadDynamicContent("welcome_test")
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({welcomeMsg: response.text});
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetchFromApi();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{welcomeMsg}</p>
    );
  }
};
```

If you want, for any reason, to keep your component **stateless**, you will have to put the `loadDynamicContent()` function on the Parent and pass the text to `WelcomeForm` as a prop. For example:

```
// Your WelcomeForm Component
const WelcomeForm = ({welcomeMsg}) => (
  <p>{welcomeMsg}</p>
);

// Whatever it's Parent Component is
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    welcomeMsg: ''
  }
  fetchFromApi() {
    DynamicContentApi.loadDynamicContent("welcome_test")
    .then(response => {
      // response.text has content
      this.setState({welcomeMsg: response.text});
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetchFromApi();
  }
  render() {
    <WelcomeForm welcomeMsg={this.state.welcomeMsg} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can pass the DynamicContentApi logic to outside:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

DynamicContentApi.loadDynamicContent('welcome_test').then((response) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<WelcomeForm data={response.text} />, document.getElementById('where you wanna render this'));
}).catch(() => {
  console.log('error while fetching...');
});
```

And where you have your component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class WelcomeForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.props.data}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ReactDOM is not defined :P

Comment: Why do you need to assign this.props.data to yourMessage when you can use <p>{this.props.data}</p> or just name the prop as message and then use <p>{this.props.message}</p>

Comment: I'm trying to help too :)

Comment: @ArberSylejmani I know that, but that is not so relevant to the case.

Comment: No, but when you answer, take your time and write a proper answer.

Comment: @ArberSylejmani sorry for the things I said. I was editing the answer. Here in SO if you don't answer fast you lost your chance hahaha. Thank you for trying to help me! I appreciate that!

Comment: Perdo, SO isn't really about chances, it's about learning and sharing knowledge. It's not a race. You don't have to be the first to answer to be the correct answer. :)

Comment: ...and you still didn't improve you answer ;)

Comment: Thanks. I understand all that. And I fixed now the detail.